# change color of text and chart - ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I would like to have the text and the geom_area fill in a specific colour.
The colour code is : #795fc6
I tried but it is not working and the fill=0.1 isn´t the right colour at all.

My dataset consists of 26 variables of 4662 observations.
For this plot I just need two variables. anaylysis_date (date format YYYY-MM-DD ) the y-axis is the sum of all observations occured at each day of the analysis period.

[image]

This is a reproducible example of the analysis date column :

```
df = c("2017-11-12", "2018-03-28", "2018-06-30", "2018-06-22", "2018-09-24" ,"2018-11-21")
```

This is my plot at the moment:

```
ggplot(data = DatasetApp, aes(x=analysis_date, fill=0.1)) +
  geom_area(stat="bin",axis.text.x=col=c("#795fc6")) +
  labs(x="Date",y="Number of Observations", title = "Number of observations pre and post GDPR", col="#795fc6")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(DatasetApp$analysis_date[GDPR_date]), color=c("#5034c4"))+
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Simply type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g.`dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first twenty rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

So in short you want the plot to be totaly purple.
The area filling can be changed with the `fill` argument outside of the `aes` argument. Text colors are set inside the `theme` function with the arguments `text` (changes color of title and axis titles) and `axis.text` (changes axis labels).

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017-11-12", "2018-03-28",
                                  "2018-06-30", "2018-06-22", 
                                  "2018-09-24" ,"2018-11-21"), 
                                format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

**Code**

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=date)) +
  geom_area(stat="bin", fill = "#795fc6") +
  labs(x="Date",
       y="Number of Observations", 
       title = "Number of observations pre and post GDPR")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = df[3,1], 
             color="#5034c4")+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(color = "#795fc6"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "#795fc6"))
```

**Plot**
[image]